# Testing multiple TComboBox values at once

Tags: delphi, testing, combobox

I'm a noob at Delphi but please help.

I have 7 TComboBoxes on a form. Their values are assigned to them using a SQL query from the same table called Numbers.

```
procedure TForm3.Button4Click(Sender: TObject);
begin

Q2.Close;
Q2.SQL.Clear;
Q2.SQL.Add ('Select num');
Q2.SQL.Add ('FROM numbers.dbf');
Q2.RequestLive := true;
Q2.Open;
cb1.Items.Add(q2.FieldByName('num').value);
cb1.Text:= '? ? ?';
cb2.Items.Add(q2.FieldByName('num').value);
cb2.Text:= '? ? ?';
...
...
...
end;
```

Where cb1, cb2.... are TComboBoxes.

I'm trying to get them to test their values (all values are text) against one another when you click on them. Specifically, if  you select cb1 = 1 from the dropdown, then if you select cb2 = 1 ...etc and you assign the same number, it should give you an error message

```
MessageDlg('Check Values: CB 1 and CB 2: Same Values Entered.',mtError, mbOKCancel, 0);
```

Which method would you recommend I use, I've been battling for two days now.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4):

Create a new form with seven combo boxes (with `Style := csDropDownList`). Then, create a

```
var
  combos: array[1..7] of TComboBox;
```

and initiate it:

```
procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  combos[1] := ComboBox1;
  combos[2] := ComboBox2;
  combos[3] := ComboBox3;
  combos[4] := ComboBox4;
  combos[5] := ComboBox5;
  combos[6] := ComboBox6;
  combos[7] := ComboBox7;
end;
```

Then you can just do

```
procedure TForm1.VerifyUniqueness(Sender: TObject);
begin
  if LongBool(TComboBox(Sender).Perform(CB_GETDROPPEDSTATE, 0, 0)) then
    Exit;
  for i := low(combos) to high(combos) do
    if (Sender <> combos[i]) and SameStr(TComboBox(Sender).Text, combos[i].Text) then
      raise Exception.CreateFmt('The fields %s and %s have the same value.', [TComboBox(Sender).Name, combos[i].Name]);
end;
```

and assign `VerifyUniqueness` to the `OnChange` event of each combo box. In addition, you need

```
procedure TForm1.ComboBoxesKeyUp(Sender: TObject; var Key: Word;
  Shift: TShiftState);
begin
  if Key = VK_RETURN then VerifyUniquness(Sender);
end;
```

Comment: If I am not mistaken, the `OnChange` event is triggered when you are navigating through the open drop-down list with the keyboard. Raising an exception or displaying a dialogue in that case might not be an optimal way to indicate the violation of the rule.

Comment: @Craig: Now I use their names instead.

Comment: @Andreas: Aah, now I understand why you wanted the integer. Using Names is better though. I'll cleanup my other comments.

Comment: @Andreas: I'm sorry, I should have been more clear. Here's a scenario. Suppose you are hating the mouse at the moment and doing all the selecting with the keyboard. You've opened the drop-down box and are moving the cursor to some distant value which might probably be a correct one. But on the way you have to pass other values, some of which violate the rule. The thing is, the `OnChange` event, as far as I can remember, is triggered with every cursor move. With your handler you'll get the drop-down list closed and the error message displayed instead. If I'm not missing something, that is.

Comment: @Andreas: And you've actually added an additional call of that handler in the `OnKeyUp` event.

Comment: @Andriy: I insist. I *have* fixed the issue. The issue *has* been fixed. Thus, there *is* no issue any more.

Comment: @Andreas: So I *was* missing something then. And I am no more, I'm happy so say. Thanks for you being so insisting. :)

Comment: Andreas: Thank you very much. I haven't tried your suggestion yet (I will in a bit) but it's hella better than all the nonsense I've been typing up. Felicitations and thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Validating each time a Combo Box's value changes does lead to a small inconvenience. If you want to swap the values of two Combo Boxes, you have to do so in a roundabout way.

- Set the first to a temporary third value.
- Set the second to the original first value.
- Set the first to the original second value.

The following code provides a means to validate all Combo Boxes at any point in time. E.g. When the user clicks the Ok button. Of course, you could still call the method each time a value changes.

The code also uses an array of combo boxes as with [Andreas Rejbrand's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5449968/testing-multiple-tcombobox-values-at-once/5450011#5450011), so I'll not repeat that portion of the code.

```
procedure ValidateComboBoxes;
var
  LCombValues: TStrings;
  I: Integer;
  LDuplicateIndex: Integer;
begin
  LComboValues := TStringList.Create;
  try
    for I := Low(FCombos) to High(FCombos) do
    begin
      LDuplicateIndex := LComboValues.IndexOf(FCombos[I].Text);
      if (LDuplicateIndex >= 0) then
      begin
        raise Exception.Create('The value: ['+FCombos[I].Text+
          '] has been duplicated in the following Combo Boxes: ['+FCombos[I].Name+
          '] and ['+TComboBox(LComboValues.Objects[LDuplicateIndex]).Name+']');
      end;
      LComboValues.AddObject(FCombos[I].Text, FCombos[I]);
    end;
  finally
    LComboValues.Destroy;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Thank you. Mr Young and Mr Rejbrand you have helped me enormously.